# I tried to use this cmd `pyuic5` but it gave can't recognize

Tags: python, pyuic

I have been trying to do PyQt5 designs, but when I want to transform it into .py file I can't. The pyuic5 error is always there in the cmd but when i try to use this command in the Pycharm terminal it works fine, I just need to change file directory in which I want the command to recognize it.

I want to use this function mainly:

```
pyuic5 -x test.ui -o test.py
```

This is what I'm facing, so if anybody has any solutions please share.

Comment: Why the tags Java, C++ and batch-file? You shouldn't randomly add tags to your post.

Comment: actually i'm new to this stuff and thought it might have a business with those...